# how to pass arguments from launch to node

Tags: ros2

I would like to pass arguments to node through launch file like below

```
roslaunch <package_name> <launch.py> argument_name:=argument
```

But, when i pass arguments like this, arguments are not being reflected in node script. How do i pass like this.
I have launch file as below.

```
def generate_launch_description():

kitti_dir_launch_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'kitti_dir',
    default_value='/media/psf/SSD/DRONES_LAB/kitti_dataset/dataset',
    description = 'Kitti Dataset directory'
)
odom_dir_launch_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'odom_dir',
    default_value='/media/psf/SSD/DRONES_LAB/kitti_dataset/dataset_2',
    description = 'Ground truth data directory'
)
sequence_launch_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'sequence',
    default_value='0',
    description = 'sequence'
)
bag_path_launch_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'bag_path',
    default_value='/default',
    description = 'Directory to save bag file'
)

kitti_sub = Node(
    package='kitti_odometry_bag_generator',
    namespace='',
    executable='kitti_sub',
    name='kitti_sub',
    # required = False
)

kitti_odom = Node(
    package='kitti_odometry_bag_generator',
    namespace='',
    executable='kitti_odom',
    name='kitti_odom',
    parameters=[
        {'kitti_dir', LaunchConfiguration('kitti_dir')},
        {'odom_dir', LaunchConfiguration('odom_dir')},
        {'sequence', LaunchConfiguration('sequence')},
        {'bag_path', LaunchConfiguration('bag_path')}
    ],
    output = 'screen',
    # required = False
)

rviz = Node(
    package='rviz2',
    namespace='',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    arguments=[os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('kitti_odometry_bag_generator'), 'rviz', 'kitti2rosbag2.rviz')],
    # required = False
)

return LaunchDescription([
    kitti_dir_launch_arg,
    odom_dir_launch_arg,
    sequence_launch_arg,
    bag_path_launch_arg,
    kitti_sub,
    kitti_odom,
    rviz
])
```

I have my node script as below

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("kitti_odom")
    self.declare_parameter('sequence', int(0))
    self.declare_parameter('data_dir', "/media/psf/SSD/DRONES_LAB/kitti_dataset/dataset")
    self.declare_parameter('odom_dir', "/media/psf/SSD/DRONES_LAB/kitti_dataset/dataset_2")
    # Get the parameter value
    sequence = self.get_parameter('sequence').get_parameter_value().integer_value
    data_dir = pathlib.Path(self.get_parameter('data_dir').get_parameter_value().string_value)
    odom_dir = pathlib.Path(self.get_parameter('odom_dir').get_parameter_value().string_value)
```

Let me know, how to pass arguments through launch file to node ...